# Navigation drawer and Action bar tabs contents overlapping in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have done navigation drawer and action bar tabs using fragments but contents of `NavigationDrawer` is overlapping on `ActionBarTabs` content.How to overcome this problem and work like Google play store app.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

            ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
            actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // create new tabs and and set up the titles of the tabs
            ActionBar.Tab mFindTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.ui_tabname_find));
            ActionBar.Tab mChatTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.ui_tabname_chat));
            ActionBar.Tab mMeetTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.ui_tabname_meet));
            ActionBar.Tab mPartyTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.ui_tabname_party));

            // create the fragments
            Fragment mFindFragment = new FindFragment();
            Fragment mChatFragment = new ChatFragment();
            Fragment mMeetFragment = new MeetFragment();
            Fragment mPartyFragment = new PartyFragment();

            // bind the fragments to the tabs - set up tabListeners for each tab
            mFindTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mFindFragment,getApplicationContext()));
            mChatTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mChatFragment,getApplicationContext()));
            mMeetTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mMeetFragment,getApplicationContext()));
            mPartyTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mPartyFragment,getApplicationContext()));

            // add the tabs to the action bar
            actionbar.addTab(mFindTab);
            actionbar.addTab(mChatTab);
            actionbar.addTab(mMeetTab);
            actionbar.addTab(mPartyTab);

            if (savedInstanceState != null)
               {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "tab is " + savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(
                                    TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0));
               }


    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,GravityCompat.START);

    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Notifications", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Messages", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Today's Task for You", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Milestone", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Working On", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Calender", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Leaderboard", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Score", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Productivity", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Badges",R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Skills Cloud", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Strength", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Your Weakness", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

    adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,dataList);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                                              R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close) 
            {
      public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
                {
          getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
          invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }
      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                {
          getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
          invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
             {
       SelectItem(0);
     }
}

     class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
  {
    public Fragment fragment;
    public Context context;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, Context context)
    {
            this.fragment = fragment;
            this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ft.remove(fragment);
    }

 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center">

 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 </LinearLayout>

 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"/>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when you click on navigation drawer that is overlapping action bar tabs ...?is my guess correct?

Comment: The navigation drawer contents are overlapping on action bar tab contents

Comment: @PratikButani i don have 10 reputation to post screenshots..

Comment: you can post images in online urls and paste here url of that images